# My redirection is removing the slash after uploading the website on Apache2 server - admin.site.comlogin instead of admin.site.com/login

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

I have a website built based on PHP/HTML/CSS and which follow the MVC design pattern.

The website is the following : https://admin.site.com

It works well on Localhost. However, when I upload it to my apache2 server, I encounter a problem. It seems that the "/" get removed automatically after ".com" . As I need to be authentificated to access the website, I'm directly redirected to the login page but as the "/" has been removed, it is not working.

I get https://admin.site.comlogin/ instead of https://admin.site.com/login/

Before posting here, I tried to check everything but I run out of ideas.

Especially the fact that this same website works on a different subdomain that I initiated for testing : http://sub1.site.com

The only difference is that that this one does not have any SSL certificate but I don't know it's something that may cause the problem.

Here my different files in Apache2 server.

**000-defaut.conf**

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin contact@site.com
  ServerName site.com
  ServerAlias sub1.site.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/sub1/interface/
  <Directory /var/www/sub1/interface/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin contact@site.com
  ServerName site.com
  ServerAlias admin.site.com
  Redirect permanent "/" "https://admin.site.com"
  DocumentRoot /var/www/site/interface/
  <Directory /var/www/site/interface/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**defaut-ssl.conf**

```
ServerAdmin contact@site.com
ServerName site.com
ServerAlias admin.site.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/site/interface/
<Directory /var/www/site/interface/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
 ...
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess**

```
`# Remove the question mark from the request but maintain the query string
RewriteEngine On

# Uncomment the following line if your public folder isn't the web server's root
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,R]
```

Do you have any insight about why it is not working and the slash get removed ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue simply :

I have added a trailing slash at the end to the redirect permanent directive.

```
Redirect permanent "/" "https://admin.site.com/"
```

I had some conflict as well with some directive. So I removed all the Directory directive to my conf file and let them only on my apache2.conf .

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```